# Git, separate branches to pull from and push to

Tags: git, branch

My repository is set up in a way that when someone pushes on "branches", a CI system checks what has been pushed and then pushes back on "master".
So, when someone pushes and pulls, it's on "branches".
But if someone commits and push something wrong, it stays on "branches", and when someone else pulls, it drags in the bad things.

I found that I can change "git pull" and "git push" commands so that they pull/push from another branches than Master, but can I separate these two settings? How can I set my repository in a way that "git pull" = "git pull origin master" and "git push" = "git push origin branches"

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am completely unable to follow what you're doing.  What do you mean, the CI system pushes back on "master"?  And what do you mean, when someone else pulls, it drags in the bad things?  At first glance, it seems like you're adding some unnecessary logic to git here.

Comment: Also, just as importantly - *why* did you do this?  What was the underlying reason to have this special setup?

Comment: I push on "branches", a branch where lies good and bad code.
CI checks the code, see if it's ok and push it on "master", the "good" branch.
I did this to have a separation between a dirty workspace and a clean workspace (also no, I can't use 2 different repositories)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off respecting the way Git works.

You can have your users explicitly pull from master and push to branches.

This way your history will make more sense in the long run no user will be confused by the hidden logic.

Comment: I know that's not a correct way to use git, but at this moment I can't change how the workspace has been set up